# How to select a column with a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code:

```
declare @MaxPointNumber INT=499, @pointNumber INT = 5;
select ('point'+CAST(@pointNumber as varchar))
from #TempHold
```

And this is the result:
[image]

point5 should be the name of column, but somehow it becomes a new value in the table. 
Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: "point5 should be the name of column".  I just  have no idea why you think this is true.

Comment: I mean that point5 is a column name at #TempHold table

Comment: Well you cant do that. You need a Dynamic Query https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated earlier you need dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @MaxPointNumber INT=499, @pointNumber INT = 5;
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + ('point'+CAST(@pointNumber as varchar)) +
' from #TempHold'


EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting from Temphold. this is acting as your column name. the table you are retrieving from.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
set @xxx=CAST(@pointNumber as varchar);
exec( 'select point'+ @xxx +' from #TempHold')
```